# Warning: SafeValue must use [property]=binding

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send an element getBoundingClientRect() to my component this way:

```
<object [fromTop]="element.getBoundingClientRect().top"></object>
```

In my component html I do this since I got a note that it was "unsafe"

```
this.fromTop = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.fromTop);

<div
style="position:absolute;top:{{fromTop}}px;">Top:{{fromTop}}</div>
```

But after adding the sanitizer I get the following message:

> SafeValue must use [property]=binding:

What's wrong? How I can let my object be in an absolute position that equals to top: `{{fromTop}}px?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{}}` is for string binding only. A sanitized value is not a plain string anymore and if you use `{{}}` the sanitization marker is removed.

You need to sanitize the whole style value and then bind it to `[style]="..."`

but a more angulary way would be using Angular bindings or directives

```
<div [style.top.px]="fromTop" [style.position]="'absolute'">Top:{{fromTop}}</div>

<div [ngStyle]="{top: fromTop + 'px', position: 'absolute'}">Top:{{fromTop}}</div>
```

This way no sanitization is required.

Comment: There's nothing special about this. This definitely works in Safari and IE. Why did you ask? Do you have a special problem in mind?

Comment: No special problem. bypassSecurityTrustStyle its not working in IE, Edge and safari.

Comment: Is this a known issue somewhere? I'm pretty sure this should just work.

Comment: I don't think its known I tested on all browser and I found some of browser not accepting bypassSecurityTrustStyle change. I tested your solution works fine in Safari and all other platform. You can test and come to know.

Comment: If you can reproduce in a Plunker, please create a bug report. I'd rather suspect missing polyfills.